# Disabling tooltip of layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, tooltip

Is it possible that the tooltip (data source properties) no longer appears when you pass the mouse cursor over the “layers” of the “Layers” window?

This tooltip:

[image]

Comment: The QGIS API doesn't allow devs to hide such a tooltip so far. But if you have a good reason in mind, you can share it or even better, create a Feature request at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues